# Need to properly reorder bars based on count after summarizing by more than one variable

Tags: r

I know how to easily reorder my bars chart based on count.  For example:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

#Convert columns of interest to factors
mtcars$gear <- as.factor(mtcars$gear)
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
summary_df1 <- mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% summarize(num1 = n())
ggplot(summary_df1, aes(x = reorder(gear, num1), y = num1)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + coord_flip()
```

Now I want to add an additional variable to fill the bars by, but I still want to reorder the bars based on the total count like I did previously.  However this is not working:

```
summary_df2 <- mtcars %>% group_by(gear, cyl) %>% summarize(num2 = n())
ggplot(summary_df2, aes(x = reorder(gear, num2), y = num2, fill = cyl)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + coord_flip()
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you can try

```
mtcars %>% 
  count(gear, cyl) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(gear, n, sum), y = n, fill = cyl)) + 
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

1. you can directly count observations by group using `count`
2. use `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar` If you want the heights of the bars to represent values in the data
3. use sum not the default mean function within `reorder`

Or try

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x =gear, y = ..count.., fill = cyl)) + 
  stat_count(geom = "bar")+
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @ds_guy consider to accept the answer if you are happy with it.

Comment: thanks - used this and it worked. similar question.