# how to reorder a flipped stacked bar in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, forcats

Consider the following example:

```
dd <- tibble(group = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'),
             type = c('auto', 'bike', 'walk','auto', 'bike', 'walk','auto', 'bike', 'walk'),
             value = c(12,32,13,60,46,34,24,3,55))
```

I am trying to get control over the way the bars are shown in a stacked bar chart. The simple ggplot call is

```
dd %>% 
ggplot(aes(y = group, fill = type, x = value)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

However, this default rendering does not work. I would like to sort the bar chart according to the total size of the bar, in descending order. That is, group `b` should be on top, then `a`, then `c`. I was unable to do so using `forcats`. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/a/49858640/2530121 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/56599684/2530121 also address this issue.